# When a weak object = [NSMutableString copy], who holds the [NSMutableString copy]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id a;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id sa;
```

I have two weak properties. The array will be release when after copy.
But the NSString not be released. I don't know the difference. Why the string not be released?

- Look the code and the output:

  ```
  {
    NSMutableString *sa = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"sa"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"aaa"];
    self.a = [array copy];
    self.sa = [sa copy];
    NSLog(@"array:%p", array);
    NSLog(@"self.a:%p", self.a);
    NSLog(@"self.sa:%p", self.sa);
  }
  array:0x6000000479b0
  self.a:0x0
  self.sa:0xa000000000061732
  ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens is that your string copy is not an actual object, but you get a [tagged pointer](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html). Basically the whole string is stored inside the pointer and there is no allocation at all. And where there is no allocation there is no memory to be freed, and so the weak reference cannot get reset to `nil`.

If you look at the actual pointer `0x617325` value and split it into bytes you find your whole string:

```
0x25 - Length (2) + flag (5) telling that it is a tagged string
0x73 - 's' 
0x61 - 'a'
```

If this was a real pointer the last digit would have to be a zero due to alignment requirements. This is the whole magic that makes those tagged pointers possible.

Comment: I think you're onto the solution. It's a combination of a) -copy gives the non-mutable version of an object (use mutableCopy to get a mutable copy) b) short non-mutable strings can be encoded as tagged pointers as an optimization c) since tagged pointers aren't really "real" objects, they don't have a lifetime, and so never go away in a way that weak pointers would be notified.

Answer (score -1):

First, your question isn't about anything useful, it's about compiler trivia.

Second, "copy" is not required to make an actual copy, it is required to behave *as if* a copy was made. Since there is no way the mutable string sa can ever be mutated, it is allowed that [sa copy] just returns sa, and sa = self.sa is only released after leaving the method.

"But self.a is nil" - it is also allowed that what I said doesn't happen.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong too. This has nothing to do with the compiler but the library implementation. And the copy there is actually necessary if you copy a mutable string. (In theory it could return a reference to the original string literal which would lead to the same behaviour, but this is not how it is done)